# Problems with editing UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with editing capabilities. The problem is whenever I delete or rearrange, the cells don't rearrange and the only cell that gets deleted is the last on in the table. The weird thing is that this wasn't happening before but it does is. Here is the code I am using -

```
self.periodArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Period 1", @"Period 2", @"Period 3", @"Period 4", @"Period 5", @"Period 6", nil];

    self.classTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*[self.periodArray count]+63) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.classTableView.delegate = self;
    self.classTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.classTableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.classTableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 34, 0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.classTableView];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger) section {

    return [self.periodArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    self.cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    self.cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (self.cell == nil) {
        self.cell = [[SchoolCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    }
    self.cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    NSString *rowString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.", (int)indexPath.row + 1];
    self.cell.rowNumber = rowString;
    self.cell.classText.delegate = self;
    self.cell.teacherText.delegate = self;
    self.cell.delegate = self;

    return self.cell;
}

#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate methods

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


}

-(void)showNext:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor == [UIColor redColor]) {
        SelectClubsViewController *selectClubsViewController = [[SelectClubsViewController alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectClubsViewController animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)editSelected:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.editClassesButton.hidden = YES;
    self.editLabel.hidden = YES;

    self.addClassButton.hidden = NO;
    self.addLabel.hidden = NO;

    self.editDoneButton.hidden = NO;
    self.editDoneLabel.hidden = NO;

    [self.classTableView setEditing: YES animated: YES];

}

-(void)doneSelected:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.editClassesButton.hidden = NO;
    self.editLabel.hidden = NO;

    self.addClassButton.hidden = YES;
    self.addLabel.hidden = YES;

    self.editDoneButton.hidden = YES;
    self.editDoneLabel.hidden = YES;

    [self.classTableView setEditing: NO animated: YES];

}

-(void)addSelected:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.periodArray addObject:@"Period 8"];
    [self.classTableView reloadData];
    self.classTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*[self.periodArray count]+63);

    self.theLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height), 320, .5);
    self.addClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.addLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.editLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.editClassesButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height)-2, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height + 5), 150, 30);

}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
    [self.classTableView reloadData];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{

    self.addClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height - 2, 320, 44);
    self.addLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 3), 100, 30);
    self.editDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height)- 2, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height + 3), 150, 30);
    [self.classTableView reloadData];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.periodArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //[tableView reloadData];
    self.classTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*[self.periodArray count]+63);

    self.theLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height), 320, .5);
    self.addClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.editLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.addLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.editClassesButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height)-2, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height + 5), 150, 30);
}
```

To add a section:

```
-(void)addSelected:(UIButton *)sender {

    [self.periodArray addObject:@"Period 8"];
    [self.classTableView reloadData];
    self.classTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44*[self.periodArray count]+63);

    self.theLine.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height), 320, .5);
    self.addClassButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.addLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.editLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + 5), 100, 30);
    self.editClassesButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.classTableView.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height)-2, 320, 44);
    self.editDoneLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, (self.classTableView.frame.size.height + self.addClassButton.frame.size.height + 5), 150, 30);

}
```

Inside the cell:

```
    self.classText = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    self.classText.delegate = self;
    self.classText.placeholder = @"Class";
    self.classText.frame = CGRectMake(145, 6, 160, 30);
    self.classText.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
    self.classText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17];
    [self.classText addTarget:self action:@selector(textViewDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.classText];
```

Comment: Do not reload the table in the `canMoveRow` or `moveRow` methods. And you don't remove any row from the table in your `commitEditingStyle` method.

Comment: And update your `periodArray` by moving an object from the old to the new index in your `moveRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: So I have fixed it so that I can delete and rearrange properly, but now if I delete and add another row, I doesn't give me a new cell, it gives me the one I previously deleted

Comment: Show your code for adding a new row.

Comment: Ok added it at the above @rmaddy

Comment: When you tap "add", do you see the new "Period 8" row as the last row?

Comment: When I click add, it shows the most recently deleted row at the bottom

Comment: it shows period 8 if nothing has been deleted, but if stuff had been deleted, it shows the deleted items. In the cell I have two UITextFields. When I add a cell, the textfield has the previous text in it @rmaddy

Comment: The problem is that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't use `self.periodArray`. It creates a fixed string from the `indexPath`.

Comment: so the numbering is working and stuff. It's just that after a cell is deleted, when another cell is added the text field in the cell should be blank, but when another cell is added, it has the text from the previously deleted cell@rmaddy

Comment: Where do you set the text of the cell's text field? I see nothing in the code you posted.

Comment: Ok I showed what is inside the cell above @rmaddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to both remove the item from the datasource (periodArray) and remove the row from the tableView:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Remove from the dataSource
    [self.periodArray removeObjectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    // Remove from the tableView
    [self.classTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: @[ indexPath ] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    ...
}
```